# PHP: user import calculate example

Tags: php, math, import, equation

So I'm new to php and I want to calculate a simple equation but I want the user to import the numbers. I've played with PHP and the only code that I have written successfully without errors are the imports.So can someone recommend a solution?

```
    Number of P: <input type="float" name="P"
    Number of RH: <input type="float" name="RH"/> <br />
    Number of D: <input type="integer" name="D" /><br />
    Number of W: <input type="integer" name="W" /><br />
    Number of C: <input type="integer" name="C" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="calculate">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are giving wrong input type**: here `input type="float" and type="integer"`

here is the list of [input type](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First of all wrap all your input fields within a form and set attribute `method = "post"` over it. And by the way `type integer and float` are not a html attribute. For your case, use only `type="text"` for each field. 
Use your form like this :

```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">
     Number of P: <input type="text" name="P"
    Number of RH: <input type="text" name="RH"/> <br />
    Number of D: <input type="text" name="D" /><br />
    Number of W: <input type="text" name="W" /><br />
    Number of C: <input type="text" name="C" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="calculate">
  </form>
```

Use post variables for the importing data.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$p = $_POST['P']; //imported value of P
 $rh = $_POST['RH'];//imported value of RH
//and so on.... 
 //now do your calculations here..
}
```

Comment: So this    `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $p = $_POST['P'];
 $rh = $_POST['RH'];
 $d = $_POST['D'];
 $w = $_POST['W'];
 $c = $_POST['C'];
 $cp = $_POST['CP'];
 $q=$p+$rh+$d+$w+$c+$cp+$q
}

Comment: yep that's right. better  you print the value of $q and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to suppress the errors with "@" and the rest of the code was fine, after I changed the types of my values.